# Mount a Luks Container on different devices at the same time

Tags: networking, ext4, encryption, luks, nas

My scenario:
I have a 50GB luks container (ext4) stored on a NAS. I can mount and work with this device on a Debian Machine, no problems.
Now I need to work on the same container on two other devices, and I see inconsistencies on file operations when this container is mounted on these devices (they are not synced).
Is there a way to work consistently on this scenario? I can change the FS, but I need it encrypted. I cannot use the folder encryption on the NAS on this case, for security purposes.

Comment: You cannot mount an ext4 filesystem (or really most other filesystems) on multiple systems at the same time. Because they have no way to coordinate access this will result in filesystem corruption and data loss. There are specialized filesystems that are able to provide shared access (NFS, Ceph, GFS, etc).

Comment: The problem is that I need a "container" file that will work independent of the server / NAS.

Comment: Not sure what that means, but your options are (a) mount it on one device at a time, or (b) expose the filesystem using NFS, since you have a NAS. Depending on your goals there are other ways of sharing files between systems (e.g., something like [syncthing](https://syncthing.net/)). If you'd like to update your question to fully describe your use case, we might be able to offer additional suggestions.